# asp.net-core 2.0 Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux

I developed application in asp.net-core 2.0 preview1. I developed it on windows with Visual Studio 2017.

Now I want to deploy it to Linux server using Docker.

I created Docker image on windows.

Docker file is:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 44305
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.Web.dll"]
```

After that running commands:

```
dotnet build -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
dotnet publish -o obj/Docker/publish -c Release
docker build -t testapi-api .
```

Then I deplyoed image on linux server with Docker and run it:

```
docker run -p 44305:80 --name api testapi-api
```

But I am getting error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. For information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: No certificate named 'HTTPS' found in configuration for the current environment (Production).
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.CertificateLoader.LoadSingle(String certificateName)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.CertificateLoader.Load(IConfigurationSection certificateConfiguration)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BindEndPoint>b__0(ListenOptions listenOptions)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BindEndPoint>b__0(ListenOptions listenOptions)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions.Listen(IPEndPoint endPoint, Action`1 configure)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.BindEndPoint(KestrelServerOptions options, IConfigurationSection endPoint, CertificateLoader certificateLoader)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.KestrelServerOptionsSetup.BindConfiguration(KestrelServerOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.LegacyOptionsCache`1.CreateOptions()
       at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer..ctor(IOptions`1 options, ITransportFactory transportFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
       at XTrader.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\wamp64\www\app\Application.Web\Program.cs:line 17
```

I followed instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/https), but nor sure if I did everything fine.

Tried to create `certificate.pfx` and add it to project but that doesn't seems to work.

If someone can help me to figure out how to get it working in this case when deploying to linux server.

Comment: Check if this issue has anything to do to your problem https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/797

Comment: Yes this issue is related, but their answer is:

"Yup, this is a big gap in Preview 1 that we don't have an easy way to setup a development certificate for HTTPS on non Windows platforms. You have to setup one manually using openssl (see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054)."

And as I said in questino I tried instruction from this link but was not able to get it working.

Comment: Did you check if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"` making any difference?

Comment: yes I have it set all the time. And SSL enabled

Comment: Did you have already found a solution for this problem? I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? Can you post your findings, please?